# How can I find the data which written with for loop in Flask

Tags: python, database, flask

I'm trying to make a database project using with MYSQL and I'm new in Flask. In this project, the user should be able to increase and decrease the number of the products in the database. I print the items in my product table with for loop. The problem is I couldn't select the item which the user selected.

Html:

```
{% for mydata in data %}

    <div class="items filterDiv {{ mydata[1] }}">
        <img src="../static/foto/atayumurta.png" alt="">
        <br><br>
        <label for="item"> {{ mydata[3] }}</label>
        <br><br>
        <label class="Number">Number: <input class="numb" min="1" name="number" type="number"></label>
        <br><br>
        <input class="addbutton" type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Add">
        <input class="removebutton" type="submit" name="removebutton" value="Remove">

    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Flask:

```
@app.route('/mainpage', methods=['POST','GET'])
def mainpage():
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM product")
    fetchdata = cursor.fetchall()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['submit_button'] == 'Add':
            number = request.form.get("number")
            print(number)
            return render_template('main.html', data=fetchdata)
    else:
        return render_template('main.html', data = fetchdata)
```

First, I wanted to see the number that the user has selected. So tried to print it but it prints null. As I said im new in flask, open for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the template contains a `for loop` for data.
In other words, the number field is not unique. So you need to modify the code. For example

```py
{% for i in range(len(data)) %}

    <div class="items filterDiv {{ data[i][1] }}">
        <img src="../static/foto/atayumurta.png" alt="">
        <br><br>
        <label for="item"> {{ data[i][3] }}</label>
        <br><br>
        <label class="Number">Number: <input class="numb" min="1" name="number{{i}}" type="number"></label>
        <br><br>
        <input class="addbutton" type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Add">
        <input class="removebutton" type="submit" name="removebutton" value="Remove">

    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Flask:

```py
@app.route('/mainpage', methods=['POST','GET'])
def mainpage():
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM product")
    fetchdata = cursor.fetchall()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['submit_button'] == 'Add':
            number = request.form.get("number1")
            print(number1)
            return render_template('main.html', data=fetchdata)
    else:
        return render_template('main.html', data = fetchdata)
```

Comment: @BerkAk You could mark an answer to be the answer. That could help others know this question is solved or who has the same question can refer it in the future.

Comment: I was thinking how can I select that item right now. I mean, there are  more than 30 items  in the database and I am looking for the item that selected by the user, not the specific item like "item number 1".

Comment: @BerkAk If you want to get all number values, you could use a hidden input to pass the count value of data. Then at flask side, you could use for loop to access each numbers since you know how many number of them. The answer is just a direction. How to use is your  decision.

Comment: I printed all the items with a number input in the html, and I want to get only 1 number that selected by the user. So it could be the 5. or 20. item but I only need the selected by the user.

Comment: If you know how to write javascript code is more easy to do that. Otherwise, you could only pass the data count to flask side and use "for loop" to find what is set.